# Creating system variable in WS02 api manager

Tags: wso2

I am trying to create a system variable in ws02 api manager.

The variable contains a special character such as / but the when being read in by the global mediator the / gets converted to a %2F

Any assistance on how I could use special characters in my variable would be greatly appreciated.

wso2 apim v 1.10

Answer (score 0):

Try with URL decoding with script mediator.

```
<script language="js" description="Query Parameter Decoding Script">
    mc.setProperty("DECODED_PARAM", encodeURIComponent(mc.getProperty('ENCODED_PARAM')));
</scrpt>
```

Reference: http://movingaheadblog.blogspot.com/2015/09/wso2-esb-how-to-url-encode-in-wso2-esb.html

Comment: Hi Bhathiya, 
We have tried what you have mentioned and investigated further however it appears the issue actually occurs after it has left the mediator.

Comment: TID: [-1234] [] [2017-07-12 16:50:58,543]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} -  company-custom_properties_in-End = End of Global Custom Dynamic Properties {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
TID: [-1] [] [2017-07-12 16:50:58,545]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ConnectCallback} -  Connection refused or failed for : esbtest.company.com.au%2Fdev:443 {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ConnectCallback}

Comment: Please post your synapse config. What do you mean by global mediator?

Comment: Hi,
Please find the synapse config here
https://github.com/brisbrain/wso2-carbon-error/issues/1

Comment: are you using a callback mediator? plz show that part as well.

Comment: No, we have a global synapse file that sets the variable and then once it leaves the mediator it should be then used by the endpoint.